# Open sourcing a project: different commit histories on local and remote repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control, open-source

I will soon open source a project. My problem though is that there were some credentials hard coded in the code. Of course, I removed them and now have a separate config file to handle credentials. **I just can not publish the whole repository because of the commit history with the credentials.**

My idea was to delete the `.git` folder, run `git init` commit and push it. With this solution I would lost all my commit history which I would like to keep. Or another idea: I copy all my project files to another folder and initialise a repo which I commit and push. I then would have the same project in two folders but in one I would have a commit history.

Is there any way to have different commit histories on your local and remote repo? Probably not I am afraid. How would you deal with this situation? Many thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

From [there](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History):

> To remove a file named passwords.txt from your entire history, you can use the --tree-filter option to filter-branch:
>
> `$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f passwords.txt' HEAD`

In your case remove from history source file with hardcoded passwords and add correct source file without passwords with latest commit